How to update pgAdmin without losing server configurations?
I have pgAdmin 4 v5.0 on Windows 10, which is installed in: C:\PostgreSQL\v13\pgsql\pgAdmin 4. This makes me think it was installed as part of a local installation of PostgreSQL, and not separately. It was a few years ago and I can't remember exactly how I installed it. I now want to update pgAdmin, which due to IT restrictions will have to install 'for me only' in C:\Users\<username>\AppData.
Given this setup, how can I update pgAdmin from 4 v5.0 to the latest (currently 4 v8.9) without losing my many server configurations and the master password? Each server connection has it's own credentials (either for a different Azure PG instance or using a different ROLE). I don't want to have to create these from scratch after updating.

PS. anyone else find it odd they don't name pgAdmin versions like 'v4.5.0' instead of '4 v5.0'? Or something clearer?
